# postgres server is not updated while psql is

Tags: postgresql

I'm not sure why when I installed postgres I ended up with the version 15.2 of psql but the 10.23 version of the server.

```
psql (15.2 (Ubuntu 15.2-1.pgdg18.04+1), server 10.23 (Ubuntu 10.23-0ubuntu0.18.04.1))
```

Is there a way to update postgres-server? I have tried several things without success. Most of them tell me I already have the latest version installed when I don't.

**EDIT**

So, I add the result of ´pg_lsclusters´, it looks like there are two version running.

```
Ver Cluster Port Status Owner    Data directory              Log file
10  main    5432 online postgres /var/lib/postgresql/10/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-10-main.log
15  main    5433 online postgres /var/lib/postgresql/15/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-15-main.log
```

How do I delete postgres server version 10? The problem is that when I run postgres and try to connect to it from, for example, django, it detects the older version and gives me a "version not supported" error.

Comment: Possibly you already have installed the latest version, you're jut not running it?

Comment: The first problem is you are pulling from two different repos's. `psql (15.2 (Ubuntu 15.2-1.pgdg18.04+1)` is coming from the Postgres community repo(https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/ubuntu/) and `server 10.23 (Ubuntu 10.23-0ubuntu0.18.04.1)` is coming from the Ubuntu repo.  The Ubuntu repo pins the Postgres version for a given Ubuntu version. The Postgres community repo allows you install multiple Postgres versions. Second, the Debian/Ubuntu packaging will always use the latest version of `psql` to connect with.

Comment: So what you are seeing is the latest `psql` connecting to your pinned Ubuntu version of Postgres. To confirm run `pg_lsclusters` at the command line and add the output as update to your question.

Comment: The most of us don't have magical capabilities, so we cannot divine what happened on your system. But keep in mind that the client can be upgraded by simply installing new software, while upgrading the server is a non-trivial activity that requires activity from your side. Consult the documentation.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Thanks for the comment. Added the result of ´pg_clusters´. Looks like there are two versions running.

Comment: There are two versions running the `10` coming from the Ubuntu repo and the `15` coming from the Postgres community repo(PGDG). The way Postgres Debian/Ubuntu packaging is set up via [pg-common](https://salsa.debian.org/postgresql/postgresql-common) this is not unusual. `pg-common` also will use the latest available version of `psql` to connect to all the Postgres servers as `psql` is backwards compatible. So there is really nothing wrong with what you are seeing.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver but when I run the django server it only detects postgres 10 and raises an error. Is there a way to delete postgres 10?

Comment: 1) Change the port number from `5432` to `5433` in your Django settings. **OR** 2) Go to `/etc/postgresql/10/main/postgresql.conf`  and `/etc/postgresql/15/main/postgresql.conf` and swap the `port` setting values so 10 is listening on 5433 and 15 on 5432. Then `sudo pg_ctlcluster 10 main restart` and `sudo pg_ctlcluster 15 main restart`. **OR** 3) **WARNING do not do this until you are sure you don't need the cluster**  `pg_dropcluster 10 main`. Then change the `port` in the 15 postgresql.conf and restart that instance.

Comment: You had three choices, what worked?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver a mix of 2 and 3.